# display image thumbnail by reading path from table and retrieving the image from folder

Tags: php

I would be grateful if anybody could help me out with this.

I have a table which stores the filepath of a set of images, e.g col filepath stores values like: ./phpimages/image3.jpg. Note that my images are stored in folder 'phpimages'

Now i want to loop through all the rows in my table and display thumbnails of the images.

Here is my code:

/

```
*************************Display all records from images table***************/
//create an instance is Image
$objImage = new Image;

$result = $objImage -> listImage();
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
//echo $num_rows."records in database";


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

$imagepath="'".$row["filepath"]."'"; // note that if i put $imagepath= "dog.jpg", it displays the image just once!


//set mime type content
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');


//create original image
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagepath);

//get image dimension
$dim=getimagesize($imagepath);


//Set thumb dimension
$thumbw = 100;
$thumbh = 130;

//create empty image
$thumb_image=imagecreatetruecolor($thumbw, $thumbh);

//Resize original image and copy it to thumb image
imagecopyresampled($thumb_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    $thumbw, $thumbh, $dim[0], $dim[1]);


//display thumb image
imagejpeg($thumb_image);
}

?>
```

Please can anyone tell me where my error lies? Many thanks for any help provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `<img src="">`

Comment: the thing is that i will have to resize the original image to the size of a thumbnail before displaying it.

Comment: ah ok ... for this purpose, I saved two copies, one thumbnail and one original (resized of course). I then call the thumbnail version when I needed it. I think it would take longer to resize on the fly if you have a lot of photos/users.

Comment: yes, that's right. I opted for the <img src"">. Thanks a lot for the suggestion, cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can output only one `imagejpeg($thumb_image);` using this method. If you want to display all thumbnails in a combined image, you should merge your images to one PHP/GD image, and then output that one.

If you would like to output thumbnail images, then I advise you to use the following tool:
http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

So when you iterate through your images, you should output an `<img src="" />` for each thumbnail.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the suggestion...I don't want to display all thumbnails in one combines image, i want to display each thumbnail in a row and append its respective info to it. So i assumed i have to loop through the paths in my table and generate a thumbnail for each of them. I hope i was clear enough. I there a way of doing this?